# Is there a way to write down chemical equations in jupyter notebook by using external packages for Mathjax?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I can't seem to figure out how to write down **chemical equations** in **Jupyter notebook**. How do we install **mhchem** for **Mathjax** to use inside **Jupyter notebook**?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code on top of your jupyter notebook:

```
$$\require{mhchem}$$
```

Comment: This works!  In a markdown cell type 
$$\require{mhchem}$$     (add two newlines) 
$\ce{Na2SO4 ->[H2O] Na+ + SO4^2-}$
More detail here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142865/arrows-chemical-equations

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the detailed explanation on how to use and write chemical equations in jupyter notebook

https://notebooks.azure.com/OUsefulInfo/projects/gettingstarted/html/3.1.1%20Chemical%20Equations.ipynb

and without any extension's you can do as well

```
 from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex                                                                                                                                                                                             
 display(Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'))                                                                                                                                                                     
 display(Math(r'\ce{H2O}'))
```

try these in jupyter